# PowerShell Remoting Collecting Performance Counters

Tags: powershell, remoting

I have downloaded PowerShell script from below link.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Perfmon-0f013da8

I am able to run this script successfully on local machine but facing issue on remote machine. I updated below code

```
(Get-Counter -ComputerName $ComputerName -Counter (Convert-HString -HString $Counter) -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 10).counterSamples
```

to following.

```
(Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {Get-Counter -Counter (Convert-HString -HString $Counter) -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 10}).counterSamples
```

Now I am getting below error.

```
The term 'Convert-HString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't exist on the remote computer you are trying to run it in. You need to paste the full function in your scriptblock prior to calling it so it has it loaded when it attempts to run it. With Invoke-Command / anything involving a PSSession on another machine, you're running in the context of that machine. If you load a function/module/variable on your local machine, it only exists on your local machine.

Edit: Updated to allow `$Counter` to be set on the local machine, then passed into the `-ScriptBlock` by using `Invoke-Command`'s `-ArgumentList` param and parameterizing the scriptblock

Example:

```
(Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    Param
    (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=0)]
    [String]
    $Counter
    )
    function Global:Convert-HString {      
        [CmdletBinding()]            
        Param             
        (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                ValueFromPipeline = $true,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
            [String]$HString
        )#End Param

        Begin {
            Write-Verbose "Converting Here-String to Array"
        }#Begin
        Process {
            $HString -split "`n" | ForEach-Object {

                $ComputerName = $_.trim()
                if ($ComputerName -notmatch "#") {
                    $ComputerName
                }    


            }
        }#Process
        End {
            # Nothing to do here.
        }#End

    }#Convert-HString
    Get-Counter -Counter (Convert-HString -HString $Counter) -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 10
} -ArgumentList $Counter).counterSamples
```

Comment: Can you please provide example.

Comment: downloaded the script from the link, copied the function from it that you're trying to call and pasted it into your script block before your scriptblock tries to call it

Comment: I am getting below error while using above code. A required argument is missing or not correct.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
    + PSComputerName        : server1

Comment: Looks like your call to Get-Counter is incorrect then.

Comment: that being said, the Get-Counter cmdlet supports -ComputerName... Why do you need to run it through Invoke-Command?

Comment: I need to get performance counters from remote machine and I am getting access denied without invoke-command. Even there is no way to pass credentials with get-counter command.

Comment: ahhhh... where are you setting the $counter variable? that also needs to be called in the scriptblock itself, or passed in as an argument

Comment: updated to allow you to set `$Counter` earlier in your script... this should be working now

Comment: Not sure if I am missing any info but getting error "The specified counter path could not be interpreted.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
    + PSComputerName        : server1" .  I am specifying counters as below                                                                                             $Counter = @" 
Memory\Available MBytes 
Memory\% committed bytes in use
"@ 
(Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock {